# Entity Recognition and Disambiguation Challenge 2014 datasets

Tags: data

I'm looking for evaluation datasets for Short Track of *Entity Recognition and Disambiguation Challenge 2014* (ERD'14) (described in the [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2701583.2701591)).

The dataset should be [here](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/erd2014/Datasets.aspx) but it has been removed. I found archived version of the this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140801072019/http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/erd2014/Datasets.aspx), but datasets weren't archived (probably WebArchive doesn't crawl large files).